# Kotlin coroutine does half the task instead of completing the task

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have a function that saves data to a CSV when a button is pushed.

```
private fun saveDataToCSV() {
        val CSV_HEADER = "activity,exerciseType,set #,reps,weights,date,dateDate,notes"
        var baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download"
        var fileName = "activities.csv"
        var fileWriter = File(baseDir,fileName)
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Saving to CSV ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //Not showing for some reason

            GlobalScope.launch {
                fileWriter.delete()
                fileWriter.createNewFile()
                fileWriter.appendText(CSV_HEADER)
                fileWriter.appendText("\n")

                for (activity in queryObjectInRealm()) {
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.activity)
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.exerciseType)
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.sets.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.reps.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.weights.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.date.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.dateDate.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.notes!!)
                    fileWriter.appendText("\n")
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"CSV saved to Downloads",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to save locally",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

The original problem that I had was the Toast `Saving to CSV ...` wasn't showing up. In fact the UI kind of hangs until the CSV is done being written. Based on what I was seeing (`The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`) I figured I should move the CSV writing task to a different thread.

And so I did with the help of coroutine. I am new to coroutine and from what I have seen I think how I've implemented is correct.. or not?

With the code above, the Toast `Saving to CSV ...` now appears but the CSV is missing a lot of data, and I'm not sure why. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: How/when do you check the data in the CSV file?

Comment: When I see the toast ```CSV saved to Downloads``` that's when I go to my CSV file in the Downloads directory of my phone to view it

Comment: `CSV saved to Downloads` is immediately printed, the `launch` is asynchronous so you're not waiting for it to finish here before printing that line

Comment: Hmm, so does that mean I should put the ```CSV saved to Downloads``` at the end of the ```GlobalScrope.launch```?

Comment: I think you should rework the function differently, because even catching the exception will not work around `launch` like this. You should probably make your function suspend instead.

Answer (score 1):

> And so I did with the help of coroutine. I am new to coroutine and from what I have seen I think how I've implemented is correct.. or not?

There are several problems here:

- using `GlobalScope` is discouraged, because it doesn't automatically handle the cancellation of your coroutines (they can live forever if not manually controlled)
- because you're using `GlobalScope` and not awaiting the launched job, you can't really know when your coroutine is done writing the file. The `"CSV saved to Downloads"` in the end is printed immediately after launching the coroutine,  not when the coroutine is done

It would be better to make the function suspend itself, and deal with the IO by switching context:

```kotlin
private suspend fun saveDataToCSV() {
        val CSV_HEADER = "activity,exerciseType,set #,reps,weights,date,dateDate,notes"
        var baseDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download"
        var fileName = "activities.csv"
        var fileWriter = File(baseDir,fileName)
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Saving to CSV ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //Not showing for some reason

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                fileWriter.delete()
                fileWriter.createNewFile()
                fileWriter.appendText(CSV_HEADER)
                fileWriter.appendText("\n")

                for (activity in queryObjectInRealm()) {
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.activity)
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.exerciseType)
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.sets.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.reps.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.weights.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.date.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.dateDate.toString())
                    fileWriter.appendText(",")
                    fileWriter.appendText(activity.notes!!)
                    fileWriter.appendText("\n")
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"CSV saved to Downloads",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to save locally",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that using `appendText` repeatedly is pretty inefficient because you will create and close a new output stream every time. It would be better to create an output stream once instead and write everything to it:

```kotlin
val file = File(baseDir,fileName)

file.bufferedWriter().use { writer -> 
    // use writer.append("...") repeatedly
} // automatically closed at the end of the use{} block
```